# Testing AngularJS inside a rails mountable engine?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, rails-engines

I'm developing a gem that is a rails 4.1 mountable engine. It's mostly AngularJS written in CoffeeScript.

How can I go about unit testing my angular code?

I need the solution to be integrated with rails assets pipeline. I've tried jasmine-rails but it doesn't work within an engine. Not easily at least.

Comment: check out teaspoon: https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using teaspoon as recommended by JedSchneider. https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon

This helped in getting it working. https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon/wiki/Testing-Engine-Assets